# Thymeleaf relative URL for style sheet

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm attempting to learn Thymeleaf, but I'm getting stuck using a context-relative URL for a stylesheet.

Here's my `<head>` from my web page:

```
<head lang="en">        
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>        
    <link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
        th:href="@{../static/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
</head>
```

If I look at the source for the rendered page, I get:

```
<head lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="./test_files/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
```

I have no clue where that path is coming from.  The "test" is the coming from the file name.  If I give the page a `<title>` tag, the "test" is replaced with the title.  But that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the relative url value.  So confused...

By the way, the standard link works perfectly in a static web page, so that is the correct path in it.

Comment: I looked around on Google and couldn't find an example that uses a relative path in the `th:href` attribute.   Your question seems valid, hope you get an answer.

Comment: Well, oddly enough that funky looking url is "correct".  If I add an image using that kind of relative URL, it works fine.  My issue was with Bootstrap.

Comment: Not quite understanding:  it appears that your rendered page showed an unexpected filter being applied.  I am not aware of anything in bootstrap that would filter a value like that.  So, curious what you figured out the problem was?

Comment: Have you used `mvc:resources` tag to map your static resources? I'm sure that would solve your problem. Also be sure to include the thymeleaf namespace and DOCTYPE `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` .

Answer (score 4):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{~/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
```

You do not need the the path to the /static folder and "~" will mark it as a server relative url. If this does not work we will need you to post any thymeleaf configuration you might have.

You will need at least the 2.0.5-SNAPSHOT Version: 
http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Context-absolute-URLs-tp3818547p3856005.html